# AS3 - Detect WHERE a collision occurred and ROTATE everything AFTER the collision point of the object by 90 degrees

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision

#### AS3 - Detect WHERE a collision occurred and ROTATE everything AFTER the collision point of the object by 90 degrees

---

DISCLAIMER
The following explanation probably makes no sense, so have a look at http://raphaelhennessy.com/misc/Explanation.png for more information

---

Essentially, I'm making a game where a lazer shines onto the screen and you have a mirror somewhere on the screen you can drag around. There is also a globe somewhere on the screen. The aim of the game is to direct the light, using the mirror, into the globe. Then, an animation plays of the globe filling with light and you progress to the next level.
After time, the levels get somewhat harder and new obstacles and challenges are introduced.
My problem is this; I got the lazer, mirror & globe all on the stage working fine except that I can't figure out how to programmatically make the lazer 'bounce' off the mirror. 
Thanks in advance,
-Raph

Comment: Laser is a line, mirror is a line, you need to find the line intersection point (line segment intersections, to be precise) which is a well-known geometrical task. After the point is found, a new laser line can be built using trigonometrical rotate functions. If all mirrors are tilted at 45 degree and all lasers are vertical or horisontal, then the task becomes even much more easier. There are are simply four possible directions in which laser can go. And calculating intersection point is also not much of an effort.

Comment: Your Explanation.png references http://raphaelhennessy.com/misc/LightStage.zip, but that's serving a 404

Comment: I was going to upload that however there wasn't really very much to upload so I deemed it to be pointless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. If you are interested you can find the code at raphaelhennessy.com/misc/LightStage.zip